# WSUS Clients Updating from Microsoft Update

Tags: windows-update, wsus

We have a Windows domain and run WSUS for managing client updates. This is all working fine, except when laptop users take their laptops home. When these machines are on their own private network, they merrily download updates from Microsoft Update, regardless of their approval status in WSUS on our office network.

Does anyone have any info on how to configure the clients so that they'll only update when on the office network, and not when they're on some random other network?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're deploying settings using Group Policy? If so, I believe this page contains the information you're after:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(WS.10).aspx

Specifically, the setting:

> Remove Links and Access to Windows Update
>
> If this setting is enabled, Automatic Updates receives updates from the WSUS server. Users who have this policy set cannot get updates from a Windows Update Web site that you have not approved. If this policy is not enabled, the Windows Update icon remains on the Start menu for local administrators to visit the Windows Update Web site. Local administrative users can use it to install unapproved software from the public Windows Update Web site. This happens even if you have specified that Automatic Updates must get approved updates from your WSUS server.